# How to use an Arduino along with a PPG sensor to find respiration rate

Tags: arduino-nano

I am working on a project where I am trying to determine respiration rate through an Arduino Nano and a MikroE Heart Rate 3 Click device.  I have been working on this for a few months, reading different research papers attempting to find an algorithm that would give me respiration rate values, but am having trouble finding an algorithm that both does what I need and encode it into the Arduino.  Does anyone know of a code that would work?
I have so far have only the basic code that reads the PPG values, but it does not provide me with the Respiration rate values.  This is the code I have so far:

```
/*
 * AFE4404 Basic Read library example.
 * https://github.com/rakshithbk/AFE4404-Library
 * 
 * On Arduino Uno -  | AFE4404 | Uno Pin
 *                   | I2C_Dat | A4
 *                   | I2C_Clk | A5
 * get_led_val() will return uint32_t values.
 * 
 * Advanced - you can modify the sample period and other
 * parameters in the library files (refer AFE4404 datasheet)
 */


#include <Wire.h>
#include <AFE_connect.h>

AFE A;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("AFE4404 basic readings -\n");
  A.init();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("LED 1 Val = ");
  Serial.print(A.get_led1_val());
  Serial.print("\t LED 2 Val = ");
  Serial.print(A.get_led2_val());
  Serial.print("\t LED 3 Val = ");
  Serial.print(A.get_led3_val());
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: You are basically asking the same thing, as the question before yours, which was asked by a different user. That's unusual in such temporal proximity. Are you somewhat related?

Comment: Yes our projects are related, as we are actually working together along with one other member.  However, while the other question asks about finding oxygen saturation from the sensor, I am focusing on how to find the respiration rate.  We have the initial code to get a reading but each need an individual algorithm with which we can determine the different measurements from those initial signals.